swapping and not swapping numbers in the document
I want to print the following two types of statements in my document:
(i) Theorem 1.1
(ii) 1.2 Theorem
I understand that (i) is the conventional numbering scheme type, and I can get type (ii) scheme simply using the \swapnumbers command. I am wondering if I can get both these types of numbering simultaneously in my document. In other words, is it possible to number one of my statements as Theorem 1.1 (i.e., without swap) and another as 1.2 Theorem (i.e., after swap) in the same document? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's a solution that assumes that the two theorem types are supposed to share the same counter. If this assumption isn't appropriate, just omit the option [theorem] from the instruction \newtheorem{swtheorem}[theorem]{Theorem}.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\swapnumbers % reverse the number placement system
\newtheorem{swtheorem}[theorem]{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{section}
\begin{theorem} bla bla \end{theorem}
\begin{swtheorem} ble ble \end{swtheorem}
\end{document}


This works. Thank you so much :)
